# Big Sur 11.2.2: Operation not permitted although Iterm and Terminal have Full disk access

Tags: security, permission, privacy

On Big Sur 11.2.2, Iterm and terminal are both granted "Full disk access" in system preferences > security & privacy > privacy

I tried to install a [third party app](https://github.com/Battleman/zoomdl/) using

```
sudo wget https://github.com/Battleman/zoomdl/releases/latest/download/zoomdl -O /usr/bin/zoomdl
```

But I got the error

```
/usr/bin/zoomdl: Operation not permitted
```

I also downloaded the repo locally and granted full disk access to the `zoomdl` executable but got same error

What should I do?

Comment: /usr/bin is for Apple supplied code only - why install there? The Unix usual directory for other code is /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to install third party software to `/usr/local/bin`. This is the default used by most Unix installers and build systems.
(Alternative directories in the root for example under /opt can be used if you have fu;ll control of how the software is built)

The folder `/usr/bin` is protected by SIP as it contains software supplied by Apple as part of macOS (In Big Sur this is even more difficult if at all possible to alter)

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaah!!!!!!!!!. Many thanks @DavidAnderson and mmmmmm!!