# Multiple "Operation not permitted" under docker despite full disk access / developer tools

Tags: terminal, big-sur, docker

I recently upgrade to Mac OS 11 (Big Sur), and since then I've been unable to use Docker for most of the things I need.

Example issue:

```
% docker run --rm -it alpine:edge
/ # apk add --no-cache emacs-nox
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/14) Installing dbus-libs (1.12.20-r2)
(2/14) Installing gmp (6.2.1-r0)
(3/14) Installing nettle (3.7.1-r0)
(4/14) Installing libffi (3.3-r2)
(5/14) Installing p11-kit (0.23.22-r0)
(6/14) Installing libtasn1 (4.16.0-r1)
(7/14) Installing libunistring (0.9.10-r0)
(8/14) Installing gnutls (3.7.0-r0)
(9/14) Installing jansson (2.13.1-r0)
(10/14) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.2_p20210313-r0)
(11/14) Installing ncurses-libs (6.2_p20210313-r0)
(12/14) Installing xz-libs (5.2.5-r0)
(13/14) Installing libxml2 (2.9.10-r6)
(14/14) Installing emacs-nox (27.1-r2)
Executing busybox-1.33.0-r2.trigger
OK: 122 MiB in 28 packages
/ # emacs foo.d
Warning: arch-dependent data dir '/usr/lib/emacs/27.1/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/': Operation not permitted
Warning: arch-independent data dir '/usr/share/emacs/27.1/etc/': Operation not permitted
Warning: game dir '/var/games/emacs': Operation not permitted
Warning: Lisp directory '/usr/share/emacs/27.1/lisp': Operation not permitted
Error: /usr/share/emacs/27.1/etc/charsets: Operation not permitted
Emacs will not function correctly without the character map files.
Please check your installation!
```

I also get "Operation not permitted" whenever trying to compile something (more precisely, when using `make`).
Now I've done my homework and I have granted both "Full Disk access" and "Developer Tools" privileges to both `iTerm2` and `Docker` (and restarted multiple times for good measure).

I've seen [Big Sur 11.2.2: Operation not permitted although Iterm and Terminal have Full disk access](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415148/big-sur-11-2-2-operation-not-permitted-although-iterm-and-terminal-have-full-di) which seems relevant, but I didn't expect this to happen within a *container*. Is this a known issue ?

Comment: Docker does not access macos' /usr directory. So this is not a full disk access issue. It looks more like the emacs docker package has an error